# TYPO3 9.5: evaluating fluid conditions for typoscript libs

Tags: migration, typo3, conditional-statements, typoscript, fluid

In TYPO3 8.5 I often used fluid conditions like this:

```
<f:if condition="{f:cObject(typoscriptObjectPath: 'lib.cookiepid')}">
```

In TYPO3 8.5 I did not define the lib, if I would not need it (depending on certain page pids f.eg.)

TYPO3 9.5 throws error:

```
#1540246570 TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\Exception
No Content Object definition found at TypoScript object path "lib.cookiepid"
```

In TYPO 9.5 I could only avoid this error, when I define this lib in TS.

what would be the best practice to avoid this error ?
Is it possible without rewriting much code ?

Comment: I would avoid such constructs. The template does not show what is being checked. Are the Fluid operators not enough? Or would it be possible to have an own small ViewHelper, which you would use the name to see which condition must prevail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd set it to the following if I wanted it to be false:

```
lib.cookiepid = TEXT
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I wanted to know.